# create multiple smaller dataframes from a larger one by IDs in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a big dataframe of almost 2mlns entries divided by 11 columns. I want to split the database into multiple smaller database by filtering by the first two columns. I give here an example of the db.

```
investor   asset    price    col4  col5   ecc 
44KL        TLSA     
451L        F
4639L       AAPL 
44KL        UBI 
44KL        F
```

I want to create a new single dataframe for each investor paired with a single asset.
This means I want the investor '44KL' to be divided into three different dataframes called TSLA, UBI and F. And this must apply for all the investors I have in my dataset.
I've tried with a parallel approach by doing this:
I first used unique() on the database to create the 'investor_ids' and the 'asset_list'
then I tried with:

```
file_names <- investors %>%
  dplyr::filter(investor %in% investor_ids) %>%
  dplyr::filter(asset %in% asset_list) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(investor) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(name = stringr::str_c("INV", investor, asset, num_trx, stat, sep = "_")) %>%
  purrr::pluck("name")

for_asset <- function(df) {   
  for(inv in investor){  
  for (ass in assets) {
    df <-  subset(df, subset = asset == ass)   
  }  
  }
}

 Parallel --------------------------------------------------------------

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
tictoc::tic()
foreach::foreach(i = seq_along(file_names), .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar% {
  
  
   df <- for_asset(db_test)

  nm <- paste0("dev/test-data/investors-rdata-assetbased/", file_names[i], ".RData")
  save(df, file = nm)
  
}
time <- tictoc::toc()
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

but I end up with the correct number of dataframes, but all are just NULL values.
Can you help me?
i then want to move on by applying computations on the new formed dfs so I need something easy to use.
I tried with split but I get a list of lists on which I don't know how to work

Comment: have you tried `split(df, df[1:2], drop = TRUE)`

Comment: That is a starting point, but i get a list in this case and I want to avoid to work with list since I have tried in the past and I showed unable to do the task. 
I'd like to store each element of the list in a indipendent df if possible

Comment: that would be a bad option.  But you can use `list2env(split(df, df[1:2], drop = TRUE) , .GlobalEnv)` if you want to create objects.  The object names will be the names from the combination of unique values in first and second column i.e. the list names

Comment: yeah, i think in this situation i would definitely go into out of memory since i would create 800k different db. 
Is there a way to store the result instead that in the globalEnv into a pc folder so that i can access each individually?

Comment: You may need to write the data into the folder

Comment: Should i use a loop for doing that? suppose the folder in which i want to save the files is "dev/test-data/investors-rdata-assetbased/"
I know how to save elements of the list but not sure how to go into that folder

Comment: You can use a `loop` , create a temp object in the loop, `rm` it,  call `gc` if memory is an issue

Comment: Why not just work with the data as it is, by group (i.e. by investor/asset).  It sounds relatively small (only 2million rows and 11 columns); I apologize, but I'm not seeing the benefit of writing each of the subframes to csv in that folder (despite providing an answer below).

Comment: I've tried with this but i get an error actually 

obj <- ls(df)

for(i in 1:length(obj))
{
  rm(save(list = (obj[i]),
       file = paste(obj[i], ".RData", sep = "")))
}

Comment: I later need to complete() or expand() each dataframe created to fill the holes between each lines (they can have missing dates) so i will increase the number of rows by a lot at the end and working with the entire db is a problem

Comment: At the end i used split and solved the saving part with 

```
setwd("dev/test-data/investors-rdata-assetbased")
library(purrr)
map(.x = names(dfs), .f = function(x){
  assign(x, dfs[[x]])
  save(list = x, file = paste0(x, ".RData"))
}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
dfs = split(df, df[c(1,2)], drop=TRUE)
purrr::walk(names(dfs), function(d) {
  readr::write_csv(dfs[[d]],paste0("dev/test-data/investors-rdata-assetbased/",d,".csv"))
})
```

A better option, by far, is to set your df to `data.table` i.e.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```

and then work with each investor/asset subgroup, using `df[i,j,by=.(investor,asset)]`